# How can I make a line chart with average value of observations at a time on a continuous x-axis in SAS Visual Analytics 8.2?

Tags: sas

I have troubles making a simple line chart in SAS Visual Analytics 8.2. I just want to plot aggregated average value of observations on y-axis against observation times (day number) on x-axis.

Line chart works otherwise nicely, but SAS VA wants to position my x-axis labels evenly, although my x-values are unevenly spaced observation times. I have been unable to find option to change x-axis to continuous type axis instead of categorical.

I also tried numeric series plot and changed x-variable's data type to a Measure. This didn't work either: Now my y-axis values are somehow not aggregated like in Line chart, but instead each x-axis time shows a cluster of observations on y-axis.

How can I make a line chart with average value of observations at a time on a continuous x-axis?